# Python thread frees memory extremely slow

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am running Python 3.7 multiprocessing on Windows Server 2019 to process large files and save results back to disk. I noticed significant time differences between threads finishing their jobs and the parent pool receiving return values. Sometimes, such time difference can be in hours. Here is an illustration of what I am doing:

```
def job(input):  
  do something  
  pickle.dump(result)  
  print('file dumped', datetime.now())  
  return 'job completed'  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
  with Pool(12) as pool:  
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(job, list_of_input):  
      print(result, datetime.now())
```

Depending on how much memory a particular thread has utilized, the process of:

1. thread prints 'file dumped'
2. memory allocation decreases slowly, like 50MBs per second
3. parent prints 'job completed'

can take quite long, minutes for 20GBs of memory, even hours for 200GBs memory.

1. Is this slowness in freeing up memory caused by python or OS (Windows Server 2019)?
2. How can I reduce this time difference?
3. If this slow memory deallocation process can't be avoided, how can I let the parent process proceed to following steps as soon as those files are written to the disk?

Comment: There isnt much here to give a well reasoned answer, but I wonder when you allocate 20GB of memory, how fragmented the enitre memory will be. How is the program loading the files and processing them ? 
Perhaps if you can shift the code to linux, and see if the problem persits you may get some insight. Overall it is my belief that linux does memory management of this order much better. Of course I have no proof of this.